# Pasting values from excel to application using HP LR Truclient protocol

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

I'm using Loadrunner 12.20 on recording a test script in a application, using Ajax Truclient Protocol. 
The workflow contains a step to copy a large number of text fields from a excel sheet/or a text file, is there a way to do the bulk copy and paste rather than entering the values field by field?

Regards
Naren

Answer (score 0):

Run a GUI Virtual User where you can then control Excel and a full blown browser instance.   This will require one OS instance per virtual user